# How to write unit test for Play Framework JSON readers

Tags: scala, playframework

I wish to write unit test for the `shipmentNumberValidator` method, where `Reads` is `play.api.libs.json.Reads`. How do I do it?

```
object Validator {
    def shipmentNumberValidator(): Reads[String] =
        Reads.filter(ValidationError(ErrorConstants.BAD_SHIPMENT_NUMBER))(_.matches(BarcodePatterns.ShipmentNumber))
}
```

The unit test should pass it a shipment number, and the method returns either successfully the shipment number, or the error message if the shipment number format doesn't match. I don't know how to pass values to this method.

The method is usually used in companion objects for implicit reads, e.g.:

```
object ShipmentOrder {
    implicit val shipmentOrderReads: Reads[ShipmentOrder] = (
  (JsPath \ "id").read[String](Validator.missingFieldValidator("id") keepAnd Validator.shipmentNumberValidator())(ShipmentOrder.apply _)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the [test framework](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Testing.html) you use (e.g. specs2), you can test expectations as following:

- Doing a `Json.parse("{expectedJson}") must be JsResult(expectedInstance)`
- Doing a `Json.parse("{unexpectedJson}") must be JsError(_)`

Using specs2:

```
import play.api.libs.json._

"JSON" should {
  "be successfully parsed when expected" in {
    Json.parse("""{"expected":"json"}""") must beLike[JsResult[ShipmentOrder]] {
      case JsSuccess(parsed, _) =>
        parsed must_== expectedShipmentOrder
    }
  }

  "fail to be parsed if expected" in {
    Json.parse("""{"unexpected":"json"}""") must beLike[JsResult[ShipmentOrder]] {
      case JsError(details) =>
        ok // possible check `details`
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Mmm, is there a way to test `shipmentNumberValidator ` without using ShipmentOrder? Reason is the validator isn't only used by ShipmentOrder, there're validators that's used by several different classes.